# php: send email when ftp-upload was a success?

Tags: php, email

i wonder what i'm doing wrong? I'm working on a ftp-upload with php. if files are uploaded successfully i want to get a confirmation email. just a simple email.

if my connection to the FTP Server was a success i'm calling the sendmail() function! it's not working!

```
        function sendmail() {
            $EmailFrom = "do-not-reply@mypage.com";
            $EmailTo = "myemail@mypage.com";
            $Subject = "File uploaded to your FTP Server";
            $Body = "Howdy, files have just been transferred to your Server.";
            // Email Headers with UTF-8 encoding
            $email_header = "From: " . $EmailFrom . "\r\n";
            $email_header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            $email_header .= "Reply-To: " . $EmailFrom . " \r\n";
            $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $email_header);
            if ($success){
              print "success with EMAIL";
            }
            else{
              print "error with EMAIL";
            }
        }
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong here? does the $EmailFrom value have to be an actual Emailaddress? It's just not working. Neither success nor error gets printed out. And nothing of my code AFTER the function-call gets executed.

thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure sendmail() is being called? I would write "test" to a "test.txt" file in the same dir, to make sure it is being called.

Comment: it doesn't matter what i put inside the function. the mail script works fine if i paste it inside of my ftp-success function. just if i do another function-call it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to sendmail() when ftp upload is success do something like this

```
$status = move_uploaded_file($src,$destination);
if($status) { sendmail(); }
```

What this will do this, first $status will hold the boolean value whether the upload is successful, and if it suceeds then it will call **your** sendmail() function